# how and when to use constructor function templates?

Tags: c++

I'm confused about the sentence below,I understand the example they used for conversion member function but not understand the constructor member function templates occasions[,helpful example given by Mankarse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922023/is-there-any-way-to-provide-an-explicit-template-argument-list-for-constructor-f/16922369?noredirect=1#16922369).

> Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name,
>   and because conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called
>   without using a function name, **there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these
>   function templates.**  --14.5.2.5 N3242

```
struct A {
    template <class T> operator T*();
};
template <class T> A::operator T*(){ return 0; }
template <> A::operator char*(){ return 0; } // specialization
template A::operator void*(); // explicit instantiation

int main() 
{
   A a;
   int *ip;
   ip = a.operator int*(); // explicit call to template operator
   // A::operator int*()
}
```

---

> The template-arguments for a member function of a class template are determined by the template-arguments
>   of the type of the object for which the member function is called.  --14.5.1.1.2 N3242

**So I need to deduct the template-argument by myself or use a wrapper.**
example given by libstdc++ when reading standard library:

```
template<typename _Container>
class back_insert_iterator
: public iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
   protected:
      _Container* container;
   public:
       explicit
       back_insert_iterator(_Container& __x) : container(&__x) { }
}
/*
 *it use a wrapper :
 */
template<typename _Container>
inline back_insert_iterator<_Container>
back_inserter(_Container& __x)
{ return back_insert_iterator<_Container>(__x); }
```

Comment: The answer is right there in the quote... you can't provide an explicit template argument list for either constructor function templates or conversion member functions. In the case of constructors, the arguments will be interpreted as template arguments to the class being constructed (even if that class is not a template), rather than the constructor itself. What more is there to say?

Comment: The constructor template arguments must be deduced (from the constructor's arguments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never provide an explicit template argument list to constructor templates. Constructor templates must always have their arguments deduced:

```
struct A {
    template<typename U> A() {}
};
template <typename T>
struct B {
    B() {}
};
struct C {
    template<typename U> C(U t) {}
};
template <typename T>
struct D {
    template<typename U> D(U t) {}
};

int main()
{
    //auto a1 = A<int>{}; //illegal -- A is not a template
    //A can never be instantiated...

    auto b = B<int>{}; //default-constructs a B<int>

    //auto c = C<double>{1.}; //illegal - C not a template

    //Constructs a C, deduces `U = double` constructor:
    auto c = C{1.};
    //Constructs a D<int>, deduces `U = double` constructor:
    auto d = D<int>{1.};
}
```

Comment: But I can't share a template-argument between constructor and class?

Comment: @yuan: See my example. You can *always* provide a template argument to the class, you can *never* provide a template argument to the constructor. I'm not sure what you mean by "share". If you want to have a non-template constructor that uses parameters from the template-class that it is a member of, then just go right ahead, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @yuan: Ok, with the updated example, I understand what you're getting at. Yes -- template argument deduction only works for functions, so if you want to deduce a class type then you need to use a `make_foo` function.

Comment: With C++17 you can now add [class template deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) to allow template argument deduction to work for classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use intermediary template class to make explicit parameter to ctor - and it will deduce your desired type

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> struct tag { using type = T;};

class My {
public:
    template <typename T> My(tag<T>) {
        cout << "ctor of " << typeid(T).name();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto a = My(tag<int>());
}
```